# hp load runner supports CAD applications

Tags: loadrunner

Please let me know whether hp load runner supports CAD software applications(2D And 3D Computer-Aided Design).

If it supports please let me know your valuable comments.

Comment: LoadRunner supports communication protocols/programming frameworks and not specific type of application. If your application uses one of the protocols/frameworks in the LoadRunner protocol list then it should work. Just download the free version of LoadRunner and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

IF your CAD solution is client-server and uses one of the expressed interfaces to store data which LoadRunner supports, then yes.

Most client-server solutions are file based.  You can build a file i/o test using a standard C, Java, VB or DLL-style virtual user but this is unlikely to capture the strict access model used by the CAD solution unless you can get access to the source code of the CAD solution and roll the file access code into a DLL style virtual user.